# Is the tag cloud the world's worst UI?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, rant

I lost my link to the work site and I wasn't sure exactly what it was called.

So I browse to stackexchange and have to guess if work is life, culture or technology. Since it wasn't in the other two perhaps it is in technology. But I will never know because I can't find it among the random distribution of little pictures. Even the browser search is no use - it claims the word appears exactly once - but can't tell me where.

Several 1000 years ago somebody invented the idea of writing and then the idea of an alphabet, then the idea of putting words in order so you can find them. They didn't come up with the idea of scattering terms at random in different sizes and different colours just because they could.

[image: Worlds worst ui]

Spot the "Workplace" and for bonus points - find Wally !

Comment: Err, just switch to the list view using the view controls top-right?

Comment: List view should be the default - since we stopped carving pictures of words on tablets ;-)

Comment: You know, if your entire point is that "list view should be the default", there are far better ways to phrase your *feature request* than "Is the tag cloud the world's worst UI?". I didn't have much of an opinion one way or another (the view preference is sticky - pick it once and you'll see that on future visits on the same device), but your post has done nothing to convince me that perhaps we should reconsider. Worst UI ever? Thanks, we tried!

Comment: p.s. you can also search from the "Stack Exchange" dropdown in the topbar on any Q&A site: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MNs8z.png.

Comment: Personally I quite enjoy the visual interface.  It's nice for browsing the most commonly accessed Stack Exchange sites.  I would say, no, it's not the world's worst UI.

Comment: By the way, it's find "Waldo."

Comment: Strange indeed that it isn't under the "Technology" tab, given that it is a technology website. Oh, wait.

Comment: @oded - "all" isn't an option at the bottom page links, just life/culture and technolgoy.

Comment: @brandaemon "*By the way, it's find 'Waldo'.*" You'll find in that vast body of water around you that there are "inhabited islands" ;) [other versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where%27s_Wally%3F#International_editions).. and we "others" do from time to time make things ;) It's English (UK) [originally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where%27s_Wally%3F).

Comment: @James Haha my bad...learn something new every day I guess

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change viewing options here:

[image]

You can display the sites as a list and even sort them alphabetically by name.  If all else fails, Google works too.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the tag cloud the world's worst UI?

No, I find it pretty useful.

> But I will never know because I can't find it among the random
>   distribution of little pictures.

You can search on that "all sites" page which returns results from the entire Stack Exchange collection of sites.

You can also view your profile on that site, which shows your network profile, sites you are have joined, and posted on, etc.

You can change the UI by clicking the "list view" icons to the right, then you have a drop down with numerous sorting options.

> Even the browser search is no use - it claims the word appears exactly
>   once - but can't tell me where.

That's nothing to do with Stack Exchange's website, that's your browser system (and the operator using it).

> Several 1000 years ago somebody invented the idea of writing and then
>   the idea of an alphabet, then the idea of putting words in order so
>   you can find them.

What has this got to do with a website page showing graphical representations of other websites ordered by creation date?

> scattering terms at random in different sizes and different colours
>   just because they could.

On the "all sites" page, the sites are ordered by creation date, they are not random.

---

You can please some of the people all of the time, you can please all of the people some of the time, but you can’t please all of the people all of the time..

With that in mind, which order would you suggest the sites would be better to be listed in:

1. Alphabetically
2. Total users
3. Total questions
4. Total answers
5. Something else

Answer (score 2):

The cloud of sites is to impress: ooh, there are so many different sites.

For navigation, there is the top navigation bar with searchable site switcher.

Answer (score 2):

> Spot the "Workplace" and for bonus points - find Wally !

I don't know why you don't you see it but I can see it under the "**[All](https://stackexchange.com/sites)**" tab. Just scroll down to the halfway.

Here is row screenshot of it:
[image]

Comment: There isn't an "all" in the list at the bottom of the stackoverflow page. So you need to go the tag cloud, then all, then realise that the hamburger logo is list view. - then look under "t" for "the"

Comment: I am at http://stackexchange.com/sites and I see the "All" in the tab in top row right before the tag cloud images start